# Remove everything except the content among Tags Notepad++

Tags: xml, notepad++

I have a file like:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Some Content Here <br> Some Content here</title>
</head>
```

I need an output like this;

```
Output: Some Content Here <br> Some Content here
```

Comment: <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Some Content Here <br> Some Content here</title>
</head>

In need to extract the content between <title></title> and rest of the items needs to be deleted......

Comment: Find What: <title>(.*?)</title>
Replace With: /1 works fine but how i can delete rest of the items from the file?

Comment: I'm doing this with HTML file,,,,,, I need to filter the titles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the regex `.*?<title>(.*?)</title>.*` that's going to be replaced by `$1`.